# I'm trying to install Xiphos

Tags: software-installation

I'm attempting to install Xiphos and when I follow the links I get to this page which is a mystery to me: https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/crosswire

What do I do with this??

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: if you want to install certain software, first check if the software is in official Ubuntu repositories with `apt-cache search some-prog` or just check software center app

Answer (score 3):

all you have to do is

go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then copy pat this commands to it one after another

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install Xiphos
```

or you can search xiphos in Ubuntu software center.

Comment: if this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I do with this??

The "mystery" page you see is a **Personal Package Archives** (PPA) page:

PPAs are for non standard software/updates. They are generally used by people who want the latest and greatest. If you are going extra lengths to get this kind of software, then you are expected to know what you are doing. The selection in the Software Centre is ample for most human beings. To know more about PPAs, see [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

If you want to install `xiphos` from a PPA, open your terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/crosswire
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xiphos
```

**Note:** You do not have to add PPA in order to install `xiphos`. Open 'ubuntu Software Center' and search for `Xiphos Bible Guide`. Click on the search results and hit 'Install'.

Comment: he doesn't have to add a PPA to install Xiphos, as it's available without it

Comment: @RonnieDroid Sure he can. I am just following his method. Thanks for pointing out, I've added the information to my answer

Comment: @RonnieDroid The PPA has a newer version ;)

Comment: @David Ashton As you're a reputation 9 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)